# NullPointerException when setting bitmap in imageview even though Bitmap got the value

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set image using Bitmap but its giving me NPE exception.

My code is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bd=getIntent().getExtras();
    pathToImage=bd.getString("Path");
    System.out.println(pathToImage);

    iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img1);       
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);

    try{ 
        if(bitmap!=null)
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

07-23 10:11:19.305: I/System.out(2502): /storage/emulated/0/grabcut.jpg
07-23 10:11:19.350: D/dalvikvm(2502): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 4% free 3630K/3768K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
07-23 10:11:19.355: I/System.out(2502): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 10:11:19.380: D/mali_winsys(2502): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
07-23 10:11:19.420: D/dalvikvm(1173): GC_CONCURRENT freed 574K, 15% free 3704K/4328K, paused 2ms+18ms, total 84ms
07-23 10:11:19.440: I/ActivityManager(423): Displayed com.example.gcut/com.example.grabcut.Grabcut: +231ms
07-23 10:11:19.565: D/Finsky(1173): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
07-23 10:11:19.735: V/StateManager(1698): destroy
07-23 10:11:26.760: I/PowerManagerService(423): Going to sleep by user request...
07-23 10:11:26.765: I/Sensors(423): virtual int IioSensorBase::enable(int32_t, int): (null) 0
07-23 10:11:27.195: D/SurfaceFlinger(119): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0xb74c7450
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output. It'll tell us where exactly the NPE is.

Comment: there is no setcontentView() method in your code..so your imageView is null

Comment: @Storm Please don't [use edits to impose your personal style preferences on other people's code](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5366552).

Comment: @ShivamVerma check now

Comment: For starters do you have the `setContentView()` method in your onCreate() as kalyan pvs mentioned ?

Comment: Ther is no setContentView() method in your onCreate() method and also remove
iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img1);

Remove "this" from the above statement

iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello @SWAG you are not set any layout in your code please set layout first

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bundle bd=getIntent().getExtras();
    pathToImage=bd.getString("Path");
    System.out.println(pathToImage);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);       
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);

    try{ 
        if(bitmap!=null)
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther is no `setContentView()` method in your `onCreate()` method and also remove

```
iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img1);
```

Remove "this" from the above statement

```
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
```

it will look like this